# Regex for string with number using node.js

Tags: regex, node.js

I am using replace string using regex.

How will i find the following string with decimal number.

```
 Section 5.1.1
 Sections 5.1.2
 Sections 5.1.3 and 5.1.4
 Sec. 5.3.1
```

Can any one assist me?

Thanks in advance.

Updated:

```
 (Sec(?:s\.|s|tions|tion|.)?)(&#xA0;|\s)?((\w+)?([.-]|(&#x2013;)|(&#x2014;))?(\w+))(\s+)?((\w+)?([.-]|(&#x2013;)|(&#x2014;))?(\w+))(\s+(to|and|through)\s(\w+)([.-]|(&#x2013;)|(&#x2014;))(\w+))?
```

Comment: It depends on what you don't want to match, too... Should `"Sect 666"` be matched for example ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: see updated portion in my question

Comment: This big regex isn't made only for the cases you show. What's the problem with it ?

Comment: i am not able to get last three decimal digit after and.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
/(^|\s)(Sec\.|Sections?) +[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*( +and +[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)*(?=$|\s)/
```

It will match substrings that

- begin with whitespace or are at the beginning of the searched string
- are followed by whitespace or are at the end of the searched string
- start with `Sec.`, `Section` or `Sections`
- followed by one or more spaces
- followed by a section number
- optionally followed by one or more `and [section number]`, where `and` is surrounded by one or more spaces.

Section numbers match if they

- start with one or more digits
- optionally followed one or more times by a dot and again one or more digits.

You can `trim` the match to get rid of eventual whitespace at the beginning of the match.

**Update**

```
/(^|[^\w])(Sec\.|Sections?) +[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*( +and +[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)*(?=$|[^\w])/
```

This one matches substrings that

- begin with a non-word character or are at the beginning of the searched string
- are followed by a non-word character or are at the end of the searched string

Rest same as above. Use an additional `replace` on the match to get rid of non-word character matches at the beginning: `match.replace(/^[^\w]+/, '')`

Comment: It is working fine.  But if there is  dot or comma at the end of the section.  The match is not found.  If i have dot or comma at the end of the section string, how will handle?

Comment: See updated answer. Please upvote/accept answer if it's what you were looking for.